# How can I open virtual keyboard

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I open the virtual keyboard when I click spesific QlineEdit area ?

I am using below codes but I've error how can I do this correctly:

```
self.phoneUi.phoneNumber.focusInEvent = self.show_keyboard
def show_keyboard(self, event):
    input_method = QInputMethod.queryFocusObject()
    input_method.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
, line 323, in show_keyboard
    input_method = QInputMethod.queryFocusObject()
TypeError: queryFocusObject(Qt.InputMethodQuery, Any): not enough arguments
```

What is the correct argument I am using pyqt5

**EDIT**

When I try with below codes:

```
   def show_keyboard(self, event):
        self.phoneUi.phoneNumber.setFocus()
        input_method = QInputMethod.queryFocusObject(Qt.InputMethodQuery.ImHints, None)

        input_method.show()
```

I get

```
input_method.show()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'show'
```

How can I solve please help

**EDIT 2**

```
   self.phoneUi.phoneNumber.focusInEvent  = self.show_keyboard
    def show_keyboard(self, event):
        print("hey")
        input_method = QApplication.inputMethod()
        input_method.show()
```

I also try with above code I can see hey print but virtual key does not open

```
pip show pyqt5
Name: PyQt5
Version: 5.15.7
```

Comment: [`queryFocusObject()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#queryFocusObject) returns a result, not a QInputMethod instance. Use [`QApplication.inputMethod()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#inputMethod).

Comment: When I try with your suggestion it doesnt open again I updated question

Comment: @musicamante Could you please look again for my question I add Edit2